# jQuery basic: How can i remove a table row when a button of this row is clicked?

Tags: jquery

```
$("#tableid tbody:last").append(html);
```

This creates table rows dynamically.
Each newly created row has a "remove" button.

Now if i click that remove button that row will be deleted.
How can i do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
 $(buttonSelector).live ('click', function ()
 {
    $(this).closest ('tr').remove ();
 }
 );
```

using `.live` to bind your event will bind it automatically when your row is dynamically added.

**Edit**

`live` is now deprecated, since version 1.7 I think.

The way to go now is using `on` instead of `live`.

```
$('#tableid').on('click', buttonSelector, function(){
    $(this).closest ('tr').remove ();
});
```

See the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Wow, I learn something new every day.  I didn't know there was a closest function.  Nice post.

Comment: The jquery documentation has some hidden treasures ;-)

Comment: what is buttonSelector?

Comment: buttonSelector is a variable holding the selector. If your button have an `id="myButton"`, then `buttonSelector = '#myButton';`

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code to delete the parent row containing the clicked button:

```
$(myButtonSelector).click(function(){
    $(this).parents('tr').first().remove();
});
```

For a live example see [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/SmfXE/2/).

For more information see [this article](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/05/remove-table-row-on-user-click.html).

Comment: If the button is in a `<td>` this removes the cell, not the row.

Comment: Button is created like this:      '<td>' + '<input class="class_button_remove" id = "id_button_' + count + '"' + 'type="button" value="Remove" >' + '</td>' ,  I tried this, =>   $('td input.class_button_remove').click(function(){
     $(this).parent().remove();
    });  , this didn't work,

Comment: The button is in <td> <input type ="button" > </td> , then how can i remove the row , not the td ?

Comment: @Jusin Ethier: I would user parents("td").eq(0) so you don't have to care if there are other parent elements

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
$('.add').click(function(){
$("#tableid tbody:last").append('<tr><td>Hi</td><td><a class="remove">Remove</a>');
});

$('.remove').live('click',function(){console.log($(this).parent().parent().remove())});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the row by this below code
HTML

```
<tr>
   <td class="text-center">4</td>
   <td>Abies Canadensis</td>
   <td>N/A</td><td>120</td>
   <td class="text-right">৳10</td>
   <td class="text-right">৳1200</td>
   <td><span class="close">×</span></td>
</tr>
```

JQuery

```
$("body").on("click", ".close", function () {
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
 });
```